# After Training Model with Keras GPU memory is full and cannot be cleared

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

so I training a model with Keras. However, when it is done with training, my GPU is almost completely full.
Using `K.clear_session` and `del model`  with `gc.collect` did not help. I can use `cuda.close()` but than I have to restart the kernel which I am trying to avoid.

Does anyone have an idea why the GPU memory is full after training and how I can free it up again.

```
n_cols = x_train.shape[1]

hist = History()


model_mlp = Sequential()

model_mlp.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu', input_dim = n_cols))
model_mlp.add(Dropout(0.2))
model_mlp.add(BatchNormalization( ))
model_mlp.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model_mlp.add(Dropout(0.4))
model_mlp.add(BatchNormalization( ))
model_mlp.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model_mlp.add(Dropout(0.4))
model_mlp.add(BatchNormalization( ))

model_mlp.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', name="fingerprint"))
model_mlp.add(BatchNormalization( name="fingerprint_norm"))
model_mlp.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model_mlp.compile(optimizer="adam", 
              loss='binary_crossentropy')

#ealry stopping if loss does not decrease 5 times we use the ModelCheckpoint to load in the best model
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1,patience=5)
mc = ModelCheckpoint('best_model_mlp.h5', monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
model_mlp.fit(x_train,y_train,validation_data=(x_val, y_val),callbacks=[es, mc], batch_size=32, epochs = 40)


model_mlp_best = load_model('best_model_mlp.h5')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth=True
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
```

This is what helped me solve the issue in case anyone else has a similar issue. It dynamically grows the memory used on the GPU.